# How to hide a column when exporting to Excel from SSRS

Tags: excel, ssrs-2012

I am trying to hide a column when exporting to Excel, although the column should still be rendered, only hidden. For instance, if I export columns A, B, C and D, only A, B and D should be visible, with C hidden. 
If I set the visibility to false within the SSRS designer, it completely omits the column.
Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655371/ssrs-export-to-excel-hide-unhide-issue

Comment: I have implemented the proposed solution on the link above, however it completely skips the rendering of the hidden column in Excel, thus, it cannot be "unhidden" in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a column group, set the visibility as hidden and to be toggled by a textbox, it will export the hidden column and put a little **+** at the top of the spreadsheet to allow you to expand the hidden column.

If you're unsure what to group on, you can always group on **1** (literally the number 1 in the group by properties). This will always show a single column with whatever you then select in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it without grouping using Report Builder 3.0. I highlighted the column that I wanted hidden, and opened the "Column Visibility...". I set it to "Hide" when the report is initially run, and then just chose a text box (not a field) in the drop down "Display can be toggled by this report item".

Hiding the column:

[image]

Excel screenshot:

[image]