# When SSRS report is exported to excel the cell height is increased. How to avoid this?

Tags: excel, reporting-services

When the report is exported to the excel the cells are expanded which is not required. I tried to remove the allow the height to increase, but that ended up with lost of data if there are more lines.

[image: IT SHOULD NOT BE LIKE THIS]

Comment: You probably have hidden characters in the data such as blank lines and/or carriage returns. Try trimming the data in the value expression for each field. e.g. `=TRIM(Fields!myField.Value)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As you said there are some hidden columns that are not used when exported to the excel. so I just hid them using rendering format true, false expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just go to column visibility option and write a expression in the show/hide based on expression and use the expression
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML",true,false)[this link will be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655371/ssrs-export-to-excel-hide-unhide-issue)